# Can Dominicans with US visas visit Niagara Falls on the Canadian side?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, dominican-citizens

We have friends, a married couple from the Dominican Republic, coming to the US on 30-day visas. We are US passport holders, and would like our friends to the Canadian side of Niagara Falls. Are they allowed to enter Canada for a few hours to a day with their DR passports and US visas? Do they need a visa to enter Canada and can they leave the US and re-enter with their 30-day US visas?

Comment: Are those single entry visas?

Comment: And are Dominicans allowed to visit Canada without a passport?

Comment: @DJClayworth I think (s)he probably does mean that - it's fairly clear that the OP is the (US) host, and the visiting Dominicans are the ones with potential issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out if you need a visa to visit Canada at [the CIC site](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-how.asp). Filling in the appropriate answers will tell you that citizens of the Dominican Republic need a visa to visit Canada, unless they have *resident* visas for the US.

You can apply for such visas. The site above will tell you how. You will also have to ensure that the US visas your guests have are multiple entry. And all of you will need to bring your passports.<sup>1</sup>

As US passport holders you yourselves can visit Canada without visa of any kind.

1. There are alternatives to passports for US citizens, as you probably know, but if you have passports you may as well use them.